# Android ViewGroup Remove Views?

Tags: java, android

I have a tabhost. One of the tab's activity is a ViewGroup.  This viewgroup manages two different activities.  I do this so I can navigate between activities within a tab.  I add the activities like so:

```
if (videoViewLive == null)
            videoViewLive = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("VideoPlayerLive", new Intent(this,VideoPlayerLive.class).
                    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();

        videoViewLive.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.addContentView(videoViewLive, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Each of my content view activities receives asynchronous notifications.  What I would like to do is somehow remove the activity/content view that is not being used.  So in essence, I load content view A, B dies, becomes null, or whatever, and vice versa.  I want to do this because the way I am managing these views seems problematic. (errors when loading a view, loading the other view, then loading the first again, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `ViewGroup.removeAllViews()`?

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of tangential to the issue here, but why are you doing this with separate Activities?

This is exactly the kind of thing [`Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)s were designed for.  There is actually a class called [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) included in the [android support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) (see also [`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html)) which allows the same kind of behavior via tabs (potentially in the `ActionBar`) or swiping.  The adapter automagically handles the lifecycles of the `Fragment`s as you navigate between them, all within the context of a single `Activity`, such that you can use the top-level `Activity` for routing events and maintaining overarching state if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would try following approach:

```
  //Add OnGlobalLayout Listener using ViewTreeObserver

View rootView = (android.R.id.content);

//Assuming you are managing these two activities inside the ViewGroup
Activity activityA = <someRef Value>;
Activity activityB = <someRef Value>;

rootView.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
    //try couple of things here
    // 1. determine which activity has focus
    // 2. you could also check position of View on screen to determine which one is active or on the top 
    if (activityA.hasWindowFocus())
    { 
       //do some action --remove other content from ViewGroup
    }
});
```